# Is it possible to compare attributes in a XACML policy?

Tags: authorization, access-control, xacml, xacml3, xacml2

The following rule says subjects with role "acme_manager" can perform any action on the resource "/acme/widgets":

```
<Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="PermitRule">
      <Condition>
         <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:and">
            <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-is-in">
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">/acme/widgets</AttributeValue>
               <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
            </Apply>
            <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-is-in">
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">acme_manager</AttributeValue>
               <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://wso2.org/claims/role" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
            </Apply>
         </Apply>
      </Condition>
   </Rule>
```

Would it be possible to create a more dynamic rule that says something like:
"subjects with the role X_manager can perform any action on the resource /Y/widgets, if X equals Y"

So I could use the same policy to enforce:

- foo_manager ... /foo/widgets
- bar_manager ... /bar/widgets
- baz_manager ... /baz/widgets
- etc.

without creating multiple, similar policies.

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course, this is in fact one of the key benefits of XACML over other authorization frameworks and definitely over RBAC.

In XACML, there are 2 elements you can use to define the applicability of the authorization. These are:

- XACML **targets**

  - targets exist in Policy Set elements, Policy elements, and Rule elements.
  - targets are for simple matching between an attribute and a value e.g. role=="manager"
- XACML **conditions**: conditions exist in Rule elements only.

  - conditions are for any type of matching including the one you are looking for. With conditions, you can compare any number of attributes e.g. userDepartment==resourceDepartment.

I recommend you use [ALFA](https://www.axiomatics.com/free-download-of-eclipse-plugin.html%E2%80%8E) to write your policies. It's much easier than plain old XACML. ALFA is a free tool developed by Axiomatics (disclaimer: I work for Axiomatics). It is also in the process of being standardized at the OASIS XACML Technical Committee.

Answer (score 0):

I think there're 2 ways to do this:

1. Define two "VariableDefinition"s in your policy: one to get the part before the underscore character, the other to get the the part between the last two slash character. [i wonder if XACML's core spec has defined such function]
   then you can use the two "VariableDefinition"s under the "Rule". then use a standart string-equal function to compare them.
2. just define a new function of your own, and add that to your FunctionFactory that your PDP uses.
   These two approach is the same, your need to apply a specified funtion on some attribute instead of using the raw attributevalue directly.

Comment: did you find the best practice to do what you want?